# How do I make a single GitHub action, with multiple triggers, create only a single check?

Tags: github-actions

I have created an action which processes a PR's labels and changed files to determine which and how many codeowner(s) need to review the PR. The details of how it works are not particularly important, but it needs to run on both `pull_request` and `pull_request_review` triggers since it depends on labels and reviews (respectively).

These triggers are currently causing two different checks to run, but I only need the latest check to pass. How can I combine both these checks into one, so that merging is allowed? (screenshot: first run fails, subsequent run succeeds under a different trigger)

[image: Action (pull_request) FAILED + Action (pull_request_review) SUCCEEDED = BLOCKING]

Here's my `.github/workflows/review-requirements.yml`

```yaml
name: Reviews
on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, unlabeled, opened, reopened, synchronize, review_requested, review_request_removed]
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted, edited, dismissed]


jobs:
  check_review_requirements:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Check Review Requirements
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Latest Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Check Review Requirements
        uses: ./.github/actions/label-based-review-requirements
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

and here's `.github/actions/label-based-review-requirements/action.yml`

```yaml
name: 'Review Requirements'
description: 'Enforces review requirements based on the applied labels.'
inputs:
  token:
    description: GitHub Access Token. Will be used to fetch PR reviews.
    required: true
runs:
  using: 'node20'
  main: 'dist/index.js'
```

`.github/actions/label-based-review-requirements/dist/index.js` looks something kind of like this (actual logic removed)

```js
if (!requiredReviewersApproved()) {
  core.setFailed("Need more appovals!");
}
```

[The documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-multiple-events) doesn't say much about this.